# FirstOrDefault is signicantly faster than SingleOrDefault while viewing ANTS profiler

Tags: c#, linq

I have a generic collection with 5000+ items in it. All items are unique so I used SingleOrDefault to pull up an item from collection. Today I used Red Gate ANTS profiler to look into the code and found out my SingleOrDefault call has 18 millions hit for 5000 iterations with (~3.5 sec) whereas when I change it to FirstOrDefault it has 9 millions hit with (~1.5 sec).

I used SingleOrDefault because I know that all items in collection are unique.

Edit : Question will be why is FirstOrDefault faster than SingleOrDefault even though this is the exact scenario where we supposed to use SingleOrDefault.

Comment: If you already *know* that the elements are unique, then the additional work done by `SingleOrDefault` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 9):

`SingleOrDefault()` raises an exception if there is more than one. In order to determine that, it must verify there are no more than one.

On the other hand, `FirstOrDefault()` can stop looking once it finds one. Therefore, I would expect it to be considerably faster in many cases.

Comment: Just to add to this answer: use `Single(OrDefault)(...)` when you MUST ensure that the value is, in fact, unique.  Otherwise, `First(OrDefault)(...)` is faster.

Answer (score 4):

`SingleOrDefault(predicate)` makes sure there is at most one item matching the given predicate, so even if it finds a matching item near the beginning of your collection, it still has to continue to the end of the `IEnumerable`.

`FirstOrDefault(predicate)` stops as soon as it finds a matching item in the collection. If your "first matches" are uniformly distributed throughout your `IEnumerable`, then you will, on average, have to go through half of the `IEnumerable`.

For a sequence of `N` items, `SingleOrDefault` will run your predicate `N` times, and `FirstOrDefault` will run your predicate (on average) `N/2` times. This explains why you see `SingleOrDefault` has twice as many "hits" as `FirstOrDefault`.

If you *know* you'll only ever have a single matching item because the source of your collection is controlled by you and your system, then you're probably better off using `FirstOrDefault`.  If your collection is coming from a user for example, then it could make sense to use `SingleOrDefault` as a check on the user's input.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt very seriously that the choice between `SingleOrDefault` or `FirstOrDefault` will be your bottleneck. I think profiling tools will hopefully highlight much larger fish to fry. Your own metrics reveal that this amounts to an almost indiscernable unit of time for any given iteration.

But I recommend using the one that matches your *expectation*. Namely, is having more than one that matches a predicate *an error*? If it is, use the method that enforces that expectation. `SingleOrDefault`. (Similarly, if having *none* is also an error, simply use `Single`.) If it is not an error for more than one, feel free to use the `First` variants, instead.

Now it should become obvious why one could be marginally faster than the other, as other answers discuss. One is enforcing a constraint, which of course is accomplished by executing logic. The other isn't enforcing that particular constraint and is thus not delayed by it.

Answer (score 1):

FirstOrDefault will return on the first hit. SinglerOrDefault will not return on the first hit but will also look at all other elements to check if its unique. So FirstOrDefault will be faster in most cases. Idf you don't need the uniqueness check take FirstOrDefault.

Answer (score 0):

I've run tests using LinqPad which indicate that queries using Single, and SingleOrDefault are faster than queries using First or FirstOrDefault. These tests were on rather simple queries of large datasets (no joins involved).  I did not expect this to be the result, in fact I was trying to prove to another developer that we should be using First and FirstOrDefault, but my foundation for my argument died when the proof indicated Single was actually faster. There may be cases where First is faster, but don't assume it is the blanket case.